# How to plot geom_area in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe (DF1)

```
 Year      V1       UR  CR        PA            FO   NA        TO 
1   1850 7377211     0 0.03615170 0.1405466      0 0.8232772 0.9999755
2   1851 7377212     0 0.03622309 0.1397468      0 0.8240073 0.9999771
3   1852 7377213     0 0.03631065 0.1389448      0 0.8247278 0.9999833
4   1853 7377214     0 0.03639766 0.1381439      0 0.8254495 0.9999911
5   1854 7377215     0 0.03647239 0.1373441      0 0.8261718 0.9999883
6   1855 7377216     0 0.03655438 0.1365248      0 0.8269085 0.9999877
```

How can I plot a geom_area type visualization like in R through ggplot for variables CR, PA, NA?

Desired output in the image below

[image: desired output similar to this]

Answer (score 2):

A good example of stacked-area (or sand) plot is https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/136-stacked-area-chart.html, which uses

```r
library(ggplot2)
time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1,7),each=7))  # x Axis
value <- runif(49, 10, 100)               # y Axis
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:7],times=7)        # group, one shape per group
data <- data.frame(time, value, group)
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_area()
```

to produce this

[image: sample stacked-area plot]

I provided that because it does a good job (I think) of showing the plot given a diverse-enough set of data. And while I appreciate the "sample" data you provided (small, not too complex), it doesn't paint a very interesting picture in its shortened form. (I'm not saying you should provide more ... though a more *diverse* data is useful, what you provided is fine for structure.)

Two steps to this for use in `ggplot2`: reshaping to a long format, then using `geom_area`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
# library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
datlong <- tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, UR:TO)
ggplot(datlong, aes(Year, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_area()
```

[image: stacked area]

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Year = 1850:1855, V1 = 7377211:7377216, UR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CR = c(0.0361517, 0.03622309, 0.03631065, 0.03639766, 0.03647239, 0.03655438), PA = c(0.1405466, 0.1397468, 0.1389448, 0.1381439, 0.1373441, 0.1365248), FO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NA. = c(0.8232772, 0.8240073, 0.8247278, 0.8254495, 0.8261718, 0.8269085), TO = c(0.9999755, 0.9999771, 0.9999833, 0.9999911, 0.9999883, 0.9999877)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Nice exposition. I think the plot that the OP is copying is proportional though, so your might want a `mutate(value = value/sum(value))` or similar after your `pivot_longer`

Comment: That would make sense, though grouping by year doesn't change the picture at all here, since `group_by(dat, Year, V1) %>% summarize(value = sum(value))` (after pivoting) is all 2s.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be interested in an area plot. First would use `pivot_longer` to put into long format. Then, with `ggplot`, you can use `fill` in your aesthetic to indicate the variables desired to include.

Also, note that I changed your `NA` column name to `NA.` as a valid column name.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(Year, CR, PA, NA.) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(CR, PA, NA.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = name)) +
    geom_area()
```

**Plot**

[image: area plot]